# Vector Iterator and insert function using typedef, C++

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator, heap

I am trying to implement heap class in c++. I am facing a problem in my insert member  function.
When I am trying to create an iterator I tried two methods both gave me errors for some reason.
Here is my 1st method:

```
#ifndef Heap_hpp
#define Heap_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
typedef int elementType;


    class Heap{
    private:
        std::vector<elementType> myVecrtor;
        int mySize = 1; //The minimum size is 1 since the first element is a dummy.
        
    public:
        Heap();
        void insert(elementType const item);
    };

    //implementation of first method
    void Heap::insert(elementType const item){
        typename std::vector<elementType> :: iterator it = mySize;/* I got the error 
                                                                   in this line*/
        myVecrtor.insert(it, item);//insert after first element(dummy)
        mySize++;
    }
```

The error:

> ```
> No viable conversion from 'int' to 'typename std::vector<int>::iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<int *>')
> Candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'std::__wrap_iter<int *>::iterator_type' (aka 'int *') for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
> ```

If I follow the suggestion (adding '&' before item) it gives me this next error in the same line:

> ```
> Calling a private constructor of class 'std::__wrap_iter<int *>'
> ```

Here is my 2nd method:

```
void Heap::insert(elementType const item){
    auto it = mySize;//iterator
    myVecrtor.insert(it, item)//here I got the error
    mySize++;
}
```

The error:

> ```
> No matching member function for call to 'insert'
> ```

At first I thought it was because the item was not a const but it didn't work either.

In my main I simply created an instance of the class and called this method. I have no idea what is the problem in both methods.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You really don't need all of this code to [duplicate the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7470af032dc95dc8).  If you are unable to understand why that code I linked to gives the error, then randomly "trying stuff" is not the way to learn what the issue is.

Comment: In the second code, `auto it = mySize;//iterator` that comment isn't true. `it` is an `int`, the same type as the `mySize` member. Furthermore, `mySize` is arguably worthless, as the vector itself has a `size()` method that will tell you exactly how many elements are in it. I assume all of the heap-algorithms (ex: [`std::make_heap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap)) in the standard library are off the table, btw, as they would make this task trivial.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I honestly didn't understand your suggestion. Can you reiterate it?

Comment: @WhozCraig Well I am trying to recreate the heap. In my case the mySize is very crucial, since the first element in the heap(index=0) should be a dummy for it to work. If anything I could've used .push_back, I can't send my first element with anything and can't send Null inside the vector. So really I just figured creating a mySize member was the best solution. Any other suggestion would be great, since it could save me the hassle!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie And concerning the fact that iterator is int IK, but shouldn't the <type>of vector be the same as the one in use, or do I simply put it vector<int>::iterator and use it on my vector<elementType>?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow you. inserting into a heap consists of (a) pushing the new value on to the **end** of the sequence, then (b) rippling through parents and siblings up the heap in O(logN) until such time as now swap is needed and the new value has found its home. No "dummy" value, null or otherwise, is needed for this.

Answer (score 2):

For starters the keyword `typename` in this declaration

```
typename std::vector<elementType> :: iterator it = mySize;
```

is redundant. Remove it.

```
std::vector<elementType> :: iterator it = mySize;
```

There is no constructor that converts an integer to an iterator. So the above declaration does not make a sense.

It seems you are trying to append a new value to the end of the vector. If so then just write

```
    myVecrtor.push_back(item);
    mySize++;
```

If you are going to insert a new value in a specified position then write

```
#include <iterator>

//...

myVecrtor.insert( std::next( std::begin( myVecrtor ), mySize ), item);
mySize++;
```

Pay attention to that this declaration

```
std::vector<elementType> myVecrtor;
```

declares an empty vector without any dummy element. So to add a new element to the vector using an iterator you have to write

```
myVecrtor.insert( std::begin( myVecrtor ), item);
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are not `int`s.  `mySize` is an `int`.

```
auto it = mySize;//iterator
```

the comment says this line is nonsense.  `it` is not an iterator.

```
    typename std::vector<elementType> :: iterator it = mySize;
```

this line tries to convert an `int` to an iterator.  The compiler complains because you can't do that.

I am not sure what your code is trying to do with `mySize` so I cannot correct it.

Iterators can be produced by calling `myVecrtor.begin()`.  Such iterators will not be valid after any potentially resizing operation on `myVecrtor`, such as `insert`.

A count of the number of elements in a vector is pointless.  `myVecrtor.size()` will maintain that for you.  Inserting at the end just requires a call to `push_back(int)`.

Comment: mySize is used to skip the first element, since the first element is a dummy in a heap. Any other suggestions?